Issue Archiving iOS App with Notification Service Extension: No Architectures in Binary, Lipo Failed
I'm working on a Flutter project, and I need to display an image in my push notifications. I'm using the awesome_notifications plugin, which works perfectly on Android. However, for iOS, I added a Notification Service Extension (NSE) in Xcode to handle this.
Initially, I encountered the "Cycle inside Runner" error, which I fixed by changing the build phase order. Specifically, I moved Embedded Foundation Extension above Run Script, and after that, I was able to build the app without any errors.
However, when I try to archive the app, I get the following error:
No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable.

My Build Phase Setup:
1-Target Dependency: Includes MyNotificationService (Runner).
2-EmbeddedFoundation Extension: Includes MyNotificationService.appex.
3-In the general tab, under Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content, I also see MyNotificationService.appex.
and If I remove MyNotificationService.appex from General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content, it automatically gets removed from Build Phases > Target Dependency.
If I remove it from Build Phases > Embedded Foundation Extension, it also gets removed from the General tab.
Here is the script I added to the Run Script phase
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
  FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
  FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
  echo "Current architectures in $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME:"
  lipo -info "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
  EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

  for ARCH in $ARCHS
  do
    if [[ "$ARCH" == "i386" || "$ARCH" == "x86_64" ]]; then
      echo "Removing $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
      lipo -remove "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -output "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
      EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
    fi
  done
  echo "Merging remaining architectures:"
  lipo -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}" -output "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged"
  rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
  if [ -f "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" ]; then
    echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
  else
    echo "Skipping replacement; no merged file created for $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
  fi
  echo "Updated architectures in $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME:"
  lipo -info "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
done

I’ve tried adjusting the build phases and adding this script, but the archiving issue persists. How can I resolve the No architectures in the binary error while keeping the Notification Service Extension functional?

